# Protect or re-route electric cabling crossing main beam in unfinished basement?

Tags: electrical, basement

I am doing some work in the basement of my 100 year old house to improve usability and reduce heating bills. In the process, I'm going to remove some abandoned wiring, and clean up some of the work that was hastily done over the past several decades. One such example is shown below, where several circuits are looped below the level of the joist space and routed around the main floor beam. These circuits go to every corner of the house with no rhyme or reason.

The beam is actually a pair of two, 2x8 beams with a 6" space between them. This was originally supported with 8x8 posts about every 10', which over the years have been replaced with an odd mix of steel columns (something I'll also be addressing during this project).

[image: Wiring passing below beam]

What is the proper way to correct how this was done? I assume that if built today, the electric lines should either pass through the beam, or in conduit beneath it (as indeed was done in a few of the later modifications).

I believe I have three options:

1. Disconnect the circuits, drill holes through the beam, and run the cables through these holes.
2. Disconnect the circuits back to the junction boxes, add conduit runs going to junction boxes on the other side of the beam, and pull new THHN.
3. Build out a slim chase around the cables, using furring strips and 1/2" plywood.

Are there issues with any of these three options, improvements, or alternatives?

---

**Bonus question:** Any need to worry about more "durable" utilities such as PVC and copper?

[image: PVC and copper passing across beam]

Comment: Thhn would require conduit even Smurf tubing would be a pain. Since you have plumbing and the refrigerant lines from a heat pump or split ac, I would put up furring strips. If you have the height to allow or a drop ceiling but on old places usually the basements are barely tall enough.